# What's the best way to get images without external frameworks in Swift?

Tags: swift

I want to be able to get images from this JSON below. Since it's an URL and can't download it directly, but through a second request, what's the best way to get the correct URLs and how does it work? On the struct of the first request, should the URL be in Data format or URL? On the second struct, should the storedProperties be URL as well?

Regarding the initialisation, what's the best way to initialise the Model on the playground? I received some errors such as Constant 'model' used by function definition before being initialized when tried to initialize the model property to run in the playground.

Thanks in advance

```
[
    {
        "albumId": 1,
        "id": 1,
        "title": "accusamus beatae ad facilis cum similique qui sunt",
        "url": "https://via.placeholder.com/600/92c952",
        "thumbnailUrl": "https://via.placeholder.com/150/92c952"
    },
    {
        "albumId": 1,
        "id": 2,
        "title": "reprehenderit est deserunt velit ipsam",
        "url": "https://via.placeholder.com/600/771796",
        "thumbnailUrl": "https://via.placeholder.com/150/771796"
    }
]
```

```
public protocol Model: Codable, Equatable {}

public extension Model {
    func toData() -> Data? {
        return try? JSONEncoder().encode(self)
    }

public struct Entry: Model {
   var thumbnailUrl: URL
      var url: URL

      public init(thumbnailUrl: URL, url: URL) {
          self.thumbnailUrl = thumbnailUrl
          self.url = url
      }

      public func toAddPhotoModel() -> URL {
          return (thumbnailUrl)
      }
}

public struct PhotoModel: Hashable {
    let albumId: Int
    let id: Int
    let title: String
    let url: URL
    let thumbnailUrl: URL

    public init( albumId: Int, id: Int, title: String, url: URL, thumbnailUrl: URL) {
        self.albumId = albumId
        self.id = id
        self.title = title
        self.url = url
        self.thumbnailUrl = thumbnailUrl
    }

    public func returnPhotoModel() -> Entry2 {
         return Entry2(thumbnailUrl: thumbnailUrl, url: url)
     }
}
```

```
let model: PhotoModel?

func fetchUrl() {

    remoteFeed.loadImageData(from: model?.thumbnailUrl) { (result: Result<Entry, Error>) in

           switch result {
           case .success(let data):
               print(data.toAddPhotoModel())
               print(result)
           case .failure:
               print(result)
           }

       }
   }


fetchUrl()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly you need decode JSON into struct or class. 
Use **Codable** protocol for this. 
After you can just load image easy:

```
guard let url = URL(string: value.url) else { return }
var data = Data(contentsOfURL: url)
var image = UIImage(data: data)
```

---

Some Changes for async

```
extension UIImageView {
    func fromURL(url: URL) {
        DispatchQueue.global().async { [weak self] in
            guard let data = try? Data(contentsOf: url), let image = UIImage(data: data) else { return }
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                self?.image = image
            }

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You should only ever use `Data(contentsOfURL:)` for short, synchronous retrieval, according to Apple's documentation: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsdata/1413892-init . Otherwise, you should use something like a URLSession dataTask, which processes asynchronously, so you need to ensure you hold onto the task so it does not get deallocated prematurely. Once you parse the first response in a completion handler, fire off the second one to fetch the image data.

Comment: @BJMiller Thank for your comment. 
I made changes for async loading - Data(contentsOf: url)

Answer (score 1):

Consider using another `dataTask` to complete this, rather than `Data(contentsOfURL:)`, which Apple says in their documentation should only be used for short, synchronous retrieval (see my comment to @Diss's answer). The revised answer should not be used either, as it's just putting lipstick on a pig. Using `URLSession`'s `dataTask(url:completion:)`  you can now handle errors and/or inspect the response retrieved, and have the system manage the background thread for you, and you dispatch back to main only when you want to.

In your switch statement in the completion of the first fetch when you get the URL string, initiate a second `dataTask`, and in that handler, convert the `Data` to a `UIImage` and then assign it, since the outer scope with the fetched model should still be alive.